# How do I control TypeScript formatting in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, code-formatting

If I select the following code and auto-format it (Edit > Format Selection), I get this:

```
function f(x,
    y
    ) {
    f(123,
        456
        );
}
```

Note the highly offensive, mis-indented closing parentheses.  What I want is this:

```
function f(x,
    y
) {
    f(123,
        456
    );
}
```

I have searched and googled and drawn a blank.  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control that. What you can control is how you insert new lines. Here's how I would write that segment:

```
function f(x,
    y) {
    f(123,
        456);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  That is deeply frustrating.  Not only can I control this in, say, C# (at least if I place my closing parenthesis where I think it should go, the C# auto-formatter doesn't move it), but I also don't see this formatting style out there in the wild.